# Determing the frame's hole mount length, for the right mount size motors

Tags: motor-mounting

How do you find out the frame's motor mount mm length?

And what motors are generally for 3 inch frames and 5 inch frames?

Example: 
3inch frames are generally for 1206 or 11XX motors?

5inch frame are generally for 2306 or 22xx motors? Does 23xx or 22xx motor number stand for an identifier?

Comment: I don't understand "motor mount mm length" - are you talking about the bolt pattern for individual motors, the diagonal distance between motor centres (the frame size) or the space available for the props? Or are you just asking for motor recommendations?

Comment: @RobinBennett, I am talking about the frame; the holes for the motor to be mounted on; to determine the distance for the right motor size, per frame, based on frame size. Example: 3 inch frames generally have 9mm length holes, apart from each other, for motors that are11xx or 12xx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://oscarliang.com/quadcopter-motor-propeller/) blog post by Oscar Liang has a table identifying the type of motor that is used for each frame on 4S (other voltages would only affect the KV). Here is a screenshot of it:
[image]

And yes, 22XX means any motor with a stator diameter of 22mm and with any height, as it is the stator diameter that will determine the mounting pattern.